# Select all img except those with certain class in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I do the Title without using `:not` selector or overriding?

PS. I'm also curious how can I do this with `:not` selector. I tried this but didn't work:

```
#div1 #div2 img:not[.c1]{ ... }
```

Comment: You have to choose either `:not()` or overrides. And it's `:not()` with round brackets (parentheses), not `:not[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `:not`, you should be able to use:

```
#div1 #div2 img { /* things that apply to :not(.c1) */ }
#div1 #div2 img.c1 { /* adjustments for .c1 */ }
```

Your syntax for `:not` is a bit off. From the [fine manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

A class selector is a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) so this should work:

```
#div1 #div2 img:not(.c1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

The :not() selector is only supported by modern browsers (Firefox, Safari and Opera), :not(IE).

```
img:not(.myimage) {…}
```

This selects all image elements that do not have the class .myimage

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used IE9 yet.

Answer (score 1):

It works with ( ) not [ ]. Check this example:

```
<div id="1d" class="blue"></div>
<div id="2d" class="blue"></div>
<p id="3d" class="blue"></p>
```

and the css

```
.blue:not(p) {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
margin: 5px;
```

}

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikan/d47Um/10/)